# What is the difference between the I2C interface and the "Grove" system?

Tags: i2c

The [Grove system](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_System) has various sensors and boards that to me all appear to be I2C-based, with a standard connector shape/size added to them - however I am not sure if this is exactly true or not - is there any way to find out? are the specifications different somehow?

For example, looking at the hub for it

[image]

I don't see any special circuitry or anything, and it claims to be an I2C hub - is it really just a form factor on top of the I2C interface?

Comment: I think "I2C hub" qualifies as an oxymoron.

Comment: Pretty sure it's i2c the connectors are labeled with i2c signal names.

Comment: @MattYoung  Maybe if they buffered bus capacitance (which they don't in this case) they could call it a "hub".

Comment: That looks like just a breakout board. Put I2C on one connector and it parallels to the other 3. Your system must use I2C and that is used to connect all the boards together.

Comment: You can connect multiple i2c devices on the same bus this looks like it's just a fancy way of wiring a bunch of slaves and masters together so just passive like you say.  The word hub is used loosely here...

Comment: @NickAlexeev I would accept that usage if they were using something like NXP's bus extenders.

Answer (score 4):

The [Grove System](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_System) is a physical standardization of various electrical interfaces including but not limited to I<sup>2</sup>C, SPI, UART, GPIO, and analog connections. The [Grove base shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/base-shield-v13-p-1378.html) is an Arduino 1.0 shield used to connect various peripherals to an Arduino-compatible mainboard.

Note that all Grove connectors are physically identical regardless of their purpose.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence: "*...connectors are physically identical regardless of their purpose*".

Comment: Might I ask what the source of this is? (I agree, it certainly appears that way... ), but it seems there are multiple "base shields", for example [this Ti board](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc-devpack-debug) supports 3 grove connectors, there seems to be an [rPi](http://www.dexterindustries.com/GrovePi/) version, etc.

Comment: @user2813274: The stupid link didn't go through for some reason. But "shields" are Arduino, TI has "BoosterPacks", BB has "capes", RPi has... something else.

Comment: The url is this: http://www.ti.com/tool/cc-devpack-debug or the "Ti SensorTag Debugger DevPack" - (actually I wanted to use the Ti board, but without all the Grove nonsense - I can do my own wiring/soldering if that's all there is to it..)

Comment: My link. And the Grove BoosterPack is [here](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Grove-Base-BoosterPack-p-2177.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would call this a "splitter".  "Hub" implies active circuitry (like USB hub or Ethernet hub).

For the most part, this Grove business is a bunch or peripheral boards with standardized connectors and somewhat standardized pinouts.

Comment: Funny, a Ethernet hub can be completely passive. And a usb hub works more like a switch than a hub.

Comment: As @Passerby mentions, traditionally Ethernet hubs were passive coaxial ports. Then 10baseT came along and the hubs now needs some simple retransmit circuit because 10baseT can't be multi-tapped. Then came switches. These days almost all ethernet "boxes" are switches even though some are labeled hubs. And some switches actually have router capabilities. I haven't seen a real hub since 2005. Traditionally, the difference between a splitter and a hub is the number of splits - 2 and it's a splitter 4 or more and it's a hub. If it's split 3 ways then it depends on the person you're talking to